# What free Powershell editors can I use on Windows XP SP2?

Tags: powershell, windows-xp

I have Windows 7 at home with Powershell 2 and I really like the free version of the PowerGUI Powershell editor.

I'd like to start using Powershell at work but we are on version 1.o on XP with SP2. I was going to install PowerGui but 
it looks like it requires some Core components or maybe even Powershell 2.0. I expect that our XP production servers may not have this version and I think it is safe to stay with 1.0 for now to avoid pushback from the keys with the keys to the production box.

My question is this:

Is there an editor like powerGui that I can use with version 1 where I do not have to install additional Powershell components that may not be present in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is actual PowerGUI script editor (version 2.4.0) works with PowerShell V1.0. My answer is that I don't think it works. In my understanding you need a version before 2.0 . I'am using PowerGUI 1.9.5.966 which works perfectly with PowerShel V1.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use all of the free and commercial editors on XP:

- PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE) ships with PowerShell V2
- PowerGUI ([www.powergui.org](http://www.powergui.org)) is a great free editor with support for code folding and intellisense, and PowerPacks to make it easy to work with PowerShell by point and click
- Idera makes another great editor (PowerShell Plus - [www.powershellplus.com](http://www.powershellplus.com)) with a strong collection of scripts that ship with it.
- DevFarm makes PowerWF and PowerSE ([www.powerwf.com](http://www.powerwf.com)), and editor and workflow tool for working with PowerShell
- PrimalForms is an editor and tool to make UI in PowerShell, built by Sapien ([www.sapien.com](http://www.sapien.com))

Hope this Helps