# Free Powershell debugging tools

Tags: powershell

Quest Power GUI Script Editor is a nice free tool for writing and debugging Powershell script.

We have Windows XP SP2. Is there any similar debugger that let's you debug step through scriptthat is provided free of charge by Microsoft that works on XP? I suspect that it'll be easier to get a MS add on tool approved than a 3rd party.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build-in Windows PowerShell ISE (GUI for Powershell) has debugging support.

Comment: As far as I undestand @chad is working on PowerShell V1.0. There were no version of ISE in this product.

Comment: @Richard Iknow and use It but here chad is speaking about XP SP2 and his professional system (on which it seems that he can not switch to V2.0)

Answer (score 2):

There's also the new Editor on the block, PowerSE

http://powerwf.com/products/powerse.aspx

Comment: Are you using PowerSE ? what do you think about IT ?

Comment: Not extensively but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Since [your question of june](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6515633/608772) there were few changes. The actual PowerGUI script editor (version 3.0.0) doesn't work with PowerShell V1.0. But you can use a version before 2.0 . I'am using PowerGUI 1.9.5.966 which works perfectly with PowerShel V1.0. I give you a copy.