# Do I need paid version of Visual Studio to develop apps for Windows 8?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8

I am about to start a project dedicated to Windows 8 OS. As far as I know there is a free Visual Studio version distributed along with Windows 8 SDK. Is it complete set that is needed to create such apps or perhaps I need to purchase full version of Visual Studio? I could not find any info about it on MS website.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is off-topic.  But in every version of Visual Studio Express you have always been able to develop and deploy applications with the Express (free) version. I haven't seen anything indicating this version is any different.  What you get when you buy a paid version is more tools, and a seamless design experience. Worth the money if you have it, but not necessary to develop real apps and distribute them.

Comment: @DavidStratton why? "•software tools commonly used by programmers": see FAQ of SO

Comment: @DavidStratton Hmm, why is it so? Isn't it directly connected to programming for Windows 8?

Comment: Because it's a licensing issue.  It's the same as any legal issue.  It's not about developmnent it's about the legal issues behind using the free product.  And it's been asked before for other versions and closed for the same reason.  If you were asking about how to use it, or how to find some setting, that's on-topic.  Legal/contractual issues are never on-topic.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363691/c-sharp-express-commercial-licensing

Comment: Ah, that was an exact duplicate.  At any rate, I may be wrong, but I've seen plenty of questions closed with "This is about licensing terms" or other.  I've flagged a moderator to ask if I'm wrong on this.  It's highly possible that I am.

Comment: @DavidStratton I do not agree, the question is about the capabilities of the express line, so on topic.http://stackoverflow.com/q/6515633/532498

Comment: Found what I was looking for.  This question is asking about #2 in the accepted answer at the link at hte end of this comment.  But again I'm just one person.  If nobody else thinks it's off-topic, the question will remain open and I've only flouted my infinite ignorance.  ;-)  No harm meant.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so

Comment: The problem with this question is that it does lack some basic research and in fact the correct information could be found in the VS section of the MS website. The answer is also temporally bound due to the frequency with which Microsoft change their content and urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

They are free, but the paid versions have more powerfull developer options.